# Subtract Results From 2 Queries

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 queries that give same results (same columns, rows) but with different data. I need to subtract the results from one column of query #1 to the same column but from query #2.

This are my queries

```
QUERY 1

SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN customer.ref IN ('emp', 'oth') THEN customer.id END) as visit_count, locations.name
FROM visits 
LEFT JOIN customer ON customer.id = visits.id
LEFT JOIN locations ON customer.loc_id = locations.id
WHERE visits.group_id = 1
GROUP BY locations.name, locations.id;

RESULTS
visit_count  |   location
---------------------------
      5      |    loc1
      1      |    loc2
      1      |    loc3

QUERY 2

SELECT COUNT(customer.id) as visit_count, locations.name FROM locations 
LEFT JOIN visits ON locations.name = visits.location_check
LEFT JOIN customer ON visits.cust_id = customer.id AND customer.group_id = 1
WHERE locations.group_id = 1 AND locations.active = true
GROUP BY locations.location_name, locations.id;

RESULTS
visit_count  |   location
---------------------------
      10      |    loc1
      15      |    loc2
      18      |    loc3
```

The results are the same, I just need to substract the first results from the second one. So the result I want would be:

```
visit_count  |   location
---------------------------
      5      |    loc1
      14     |    loc2
      17     |    loc3
```

Is there a way to join them together and subtract one column from another?

Comment: Well, you can turn both queries to subqueries, `join` the results and do the computation in the outer query. But there are possibly more efficient solutions available; for us to provide a suggestion, you would need to show the data in the original tables, not just the results of the existing queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the most straightforward answer:

```
SELECT b.visit_count-a.visit_count, a.location
FROM
(
  SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN customer.ref IN ('emp', 'oth') THEN customer.id END) as visit_count, locations.name
  FROM visits 
  LEFT JOIN customer ON customer.id = visits.id
  LEFT JOIN locations ON customer.loc_id = locations.id
  WHERE visits.group_id = 1
  GROUP BY locations.name, locations.id;
) as a
(
  SELECT COUNT(customer.id) as visit_count, locations.name FROM locations 
  LEFT JOIN visits ON locations.name = visits.location_check
  LEFT JOIN customer ON visits.cust_id = customer.id AND customer.group_id = 1
  WHERE locations.group_id = 1 AND locations.active = true
  GROUP BY locations.location_name, locations.id;
) as b
WHERE a.location=b.location;
```

This is obviously merely a copy/paste of what you provided, but there seem to be some details that need to be ironed out, like `customer.id = visits.id` in one query, and `customer.id = visits.cust_id` in the other query.

You seem to want to get the number of total visits at each location, minus the ones where `customer.ref` is either `emp` or `oth`.  If that's the case, I would suppose you just want something like this:

```
SELECT count(*), l.name as location
FROM visits v
JOIN customer c ON c.id=v.id
JOIN locations l ON l.id=c.loc_id
WHERE v.group_id = 1
AND l.active
AND c.ref NOT IN ('emp','oth')
GROUP BY l.name;
```

Of course, the *correct* query depends on your table structure, which we don't really know here, as the column names seem not to be consistent.

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](http://enterprisedb.com)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! This really helped me! :)